# Scipy Spline Interpolation Parameter

Tags: scipy

Documentation in scipy.interpolate (found at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) states:

"The parameter variable is given with the keyword argument, u, which defaults to an equally-spaced monotonic sequence between 0 and 1."

From experimenting with the function in 2D, it appears that the parameter is the length along the curve. Here's a snippet my test script:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

n = 20

iota = np.arange(n)
gamma = 5
theta = np.pi/2 * (1.0 * iota / (n-1)) ** gamma

r = np.cos(theta)
z = np.sin(theta)

spl, u = splprep([r,z])
spline = splev(u, spl)

# Sampled point at half-length?
test = splev(0.5, spl)

plt.plot(r, z, '*')
plt.plot(spline[0], spline[1], '*', color = 'red')
plt.plot(test[0], test[1], '*', color = 'cyan')

# Exact mid-point.
plt.plot(np.sqrt(2)/2, np.sqrt(2)/2, '*', color = 'purple')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The above statement does not (to me) seem to clearly convey this behavior. Would anyone have input on this?

Answer (score 1):

> The parameter variable is given with the keyword argument, $u$, which
>   defaults to an equally-spaced monotonic sequence between...

When calling the function splprep you *may* pass an argument of $u$. This argument $u$ should be the same length as your data, and the algorithm will treat it as the *parameter* of the curve, sometimes called the 'time' along the curve. Later, when using splev, the argument x you supply to it, is the 'time' for which you want the interpolated value.

I edited your code a bit to try experimenting with this feature. You see that upon changing $beta$, you would get overshoots or undershoots in your interpolation.

I also think that the documentation you linked to is incorrect, because setting beta to 1 does not yield the same result as omitting the $u$ argument to splprep. In fact, I tested it, and the default $u$ is cumulative sum of the segment lengths. The code below prints False:

```
_, u_default = splprep([r,z])
C = np.cumsum((np.diff(np.array([r,z]).transpose(),axis=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5)
C /= C[-1]
C = np.concatenate(([0],C))
print(np.any(u_default-C))
```

Some more experiments with the $u$ argument:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
plt.figure()

n = 20

iota = np.arange(n)
gamma = 5
beta = 2
theta = np.pi/2 * (1.0 * iota / (n-1)) ** gamma

r = np.cos(theta)
z = np.sin(theta)

u_arg = np.linspace(0,1,n)**beta
spl, u = splprep([r,z],u=u_arg)
print(np.any(u_arg!=u))
spline = splev(u, spl)

# Sampled point at half-length?
test = splev(0.5, spl)

plt.plot(r, z, 'v','b')
plt.plot(spline[0], spline[1], '^', color = 'red')
plt.plot(test[0], test[1], 'x', color = 'cyan')

# Exact mid-point.
plt.plot(np.sqrt(2)/2, np.sqrt(2)/2, '+', color = 'purple')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```